# Can you practice art on Chol Hamoed if you do it digitally?

Tags: halacha, technology, melacha-creative-work, chol-hamoed, art

As I understand it, traditional writing and art is for the most part forbidden on Chol Hamoed, but typing something up on the computer or your phone is generally allowed because it's not permanent and is not Ma'aseh Uman.

However, can this be applied to digital art or will it not pass the Ma'aseh Uman test?

It should be noted that the case I'm talking about is where an artist would like to practice his or her craft on the Chol Hamoed, but not necessarily sell the produced art.

If it is permitted, does it matter in which format it's done? (iPad, pen display on your computer, mouse, etc).